# sort NSDictionary values by key alphabetical order

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdictionary

I can get an array of dictionary keys sorted by values, but how to I get an array of values sorted by dictionary keys? I've been looking everywhere with no luck. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are the values in your dictionary? Are they c types or objects?

Comment: NSNumber objects are the values. I just need to order the keys and then create an array of objects from the values based on that ordering.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This might work:

```
NSArray * sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray * objects = [dict objectsForKeys: sortedKeys notFoundMarker: [NSNull null]];
```

---

*or in Swift*

```
let objects = dict.keys.sorted().flatMap{ dict[$0] }
```

or

```
let objects = dict.sorted{ $0.0 < $1.0 }.map{ $1 }
```

…and that is why you should start developing in Swift

Comment: hm, this is crashing for me. not sure why yet.

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:]: marker is nil'`

Comment: It looks like the notFoundMarker must contain something. I guess what it contains is irrelevant in this example, as the keys will always be found. Updated my answer.

Comment: This method is superfluous, you can get a sorted array directly from  the dictionary, without first needing to call allKeys

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - see my comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 3):

My experience shows that sorting `NSDictionary` by keys is not much useful. Although after `logging` the `NSDictionary` they seem to be sorted, when needed to put them in a tableview they are not in order any more.

I suggest storing the keys in an `NSArray` property and then query the `NSDictionary` objects according to the order of the keys in the `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2):

I created a category on NSDictionary to get this accomplished:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Extra)

-(NSArray *) sortedKeys {
    return [[self allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}

-(NSArray *) allValuesSortedByKey {
    return [self objectsForKeys:self.sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
}

-(id) firstKey {
    return [self.sortedKeys firstObject];
}

-(id) firstValue {
    return [self valueForKey: [self firstKey]];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is really excellent, even if I only found it nearly 10 years later.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to construct the array of sorted dictionary keys, then create another array of the values based on the array of keys:

```
//Construct array of sorted keys
NSArray keyarray = ... //etc

NSMutableArray valuearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id key in keyarray) {
    [valuearray addObject:[dict objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: i agree and considered this, but was hoping for a more elegant solution that doesn't require enumeration