# can we sort dictionary in alphabetically in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sorting, sdk

I am using this code

```
NSArray *sortedKeysArray = 
[myDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

but it results in this error

```
unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7c371a00
```

How can this be resolved?

Help will be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612299/sort-nsdictionary-values-by-key-alphabetical-order

Comment: Following url may help you [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612299/sort-nsdictionary-values-by-key-alphabetical-order

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:) by Apple

An array of `NSString` objects can be sorted by using the [caseInsensitiveCompare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare:) method declared in the `NSString` class. Assuming anArray exists, a sorted version of the array can be created in this way:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```